# Assessing which player "wins" a series of predictions

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation, score-function

A group of friends makes predictions about the outcome of the elections and we would like to assess who's predictions are closer to the final "outcome". For example, Here is a table of predictions for 4 parties (A, B, C, D) and the final "outcome" of the elections:

```
| Party  | Andrew | Bob  | Claire | Dominic | Eva  | Outcome |
|--------|--------|------|--------|---------|------|---------|
| A      | 44     | 41   | 44     | 45      | 43   | 44      |
| B      | 36     | 41   | 43     | 40      | 42   | 41      |
| C      | 7      | 8.5  | 5      | 7       | 8    | 7       |
| D      | 8      | 3    | 5      | 5       | 4    | 3       |
| Others | 5      | 6.5  | 3      | 3       | 3    | 5       |
| Sum    | 100%   | 100% | 100%   | 100%    | 100% | 100%    |
```

It is tempting to use the formula for standard deviation:
$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \mu)^2} {n}}
$$
to calculate each player's deviation from the final "outcome". For example, Eva's standard deviation is:
$$
\sigma_E = \sqrt{\frac{(43-44)^2+(42-41)^2+(7-7)^2+(4-3)^2+(3-5)^2} {5}} = 1.26
$$
which is the lowest of the lot. However, this is not a correct use of the standard deviation formula since we are not measuring the st. dev. of a sample with a given mean. Furthermore, the sum of predictions for the 4 parties + Other always sums up to 100 so the "free" predictions are really 4, not 5. My questions are:

1. Is this calculation valid?
2. Is there a better way to formulate the problem, without getting into parametric tests?

Comment: What do the numbers mean? How does one assess whether a prediction is "good" or "bad"? How should one quantify *how* good it is?  For instance, if each election has a single winner determined by the plurality vote, then the standard deviation will have little or nothing to do with how accurately an individual predicts the outcome, because it primarily measures how accurately they predicted the portion of the popular vote given to the minority parties, which is nearly irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I clarified the objective of the game, which is to get as close to the final outcome of the election as possible.

Comment: Thank you for making that more specific. However, "close" can be measured in many different ways. Several might be germane to your problem, depending on how you quantify the discrepancy between a prediction and an outcome. You could use the difference, the relative difference, the log ratio, or the difference of logits, for instance.

Comment: How would you interpret and formulate the problem? Please post a response below.

Comment: As @Glen_b points out in his answer, this is something you will have to tell us: we cannot tell you why you are doing this or how you should go about measuring the accuracy of a prediction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quantity you have specified is not a standard deviation, because $\mu$ is not the mean prediction.

It's called a [root-mean-square deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation), and it's a common measure of accuracy.

However, it's not necessarily a *suitable* measure of accuracy in this case.

1) the variance of sample proportions is larger near $\frac{1}{2}$ than near the ends -- in some sense it's "easier" to get within a few percent of a very small proportion than one near $\frac{1}{2}$, so you might want to weight accuracy in different regions according to how hard it would be to predict proportions in that region.

2) in terms of predicting outcomes of elections, the relationship between the proportions and the outcomes may be relatively complex -- and depend on the particular kind of election -- a vote is handled very differently when voting for an American president (where accuracy on anything but the top two matter not at all) compared to voting for a StackExchange moderator election, the Irish house of representatives or the Australian Senate (where accuracy in the "small party" votes may be much more important).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the RMSD. Point 1) is correct but let's assume the variance is the same for all parties (i.e. we have no prior knowledge of scores of other years). Point 2) is not of interest. I'm only interested in the given (fictional) example.

Comment: If your only task is to approximate those proportions, then yes, you could use that RMSD measure you suggest, as long as that represents your loss function/what represents 'close' for your purposes when it's small.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "proper score function", which was intended just for your purpose!  You can read about proper score functions here: [Metrics to asses the ability of a model to predict a probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191955/metrics-to-asses-the-ability-of-a-model-to-predict-a-probability/191959#191959)  or at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule